# i have made this code for removing a specific word from a string

Tags: java, string, class, loops

```
class abc
{
    void main(String s)
    {
        s=s+" ";
        String st="";String sen="";
        int l=s.length();
        char ch;
        for(int i=0;i<l-1;i++)
        {
            ch=s.charAt(i);
           if (ch!=' ')
           {
               st=st+ch;

        }
        else
        {
            if(st.equalsIgnoreCase("The"))
            {
                sen=sen+" "+st;
                st="";
            }
        }
    }
       System.out.println("The new string is"+st);
    }
}
```

I am attempting the remove the word "The" from a string.

Input:
s = "The big cat"

Expected output:
"big cat"

Actual ouput:
"bigca"

Comment: Could you please be more descriptive, what error is the program giving? it doesn't work isn't that helpful, we already know that otherwise you wouldn't be here, but what isn't working is what we are interested in

Comment: like it's removing "the" if its the first word of the string

Comment: Note for future questions: "it it's not working" is not specific enough, you should at least describe in what way it is not running, i.e. what do you expect, what do you get instead, any errors you get and possible examples of input and expected output.

Comment: and then the rest of the string comes up as like "havebeenthisgood"

Comment: I tested your code and it works, it removes the starting "The" from a sentence however it concatenates the words e.g. "the big cat" becomes "bigca" (no spaces and the last character is missing)

Comment: I guess it's for learning purposes so the "easy" way using `String.replaceAll()` might not be what you want. One thing you should do is step through your code with a debugger and check what each statement is doing. That way you should be able to quickly narrow down the error. - I could provide a solution here but you might not learn as much as when trying to debug and solve it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Changed a bit your for loop code:

```
    for(int i=0;i<=l-1;i++)
    {
        ch=s.charAt(i);
        st=st+ch;
        if(st.equalsIgnoreCase("The"))
        {
            sen=sen+" "+st;
            st="";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The new string is: "+st);
```

Two things:

1) the for loop requires to loop till the last character of the input string (`i<=l-1` instead of `i<l-1`)

2) the following code was trimming the spaces and concatenating the words together, so I moved out the `st=st+ch` outside the `if` statement, not sure if you wanted this purposely:

```
if (ch!=' ')
{
    st=st+ch;

}
```

**Full code and input:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="the big cat is the best";
    String st="";
    String sen="";
    int l=s.length();
    char ch;
    for(int i=0;i<=l-1;i++)
    {
        ch=s.charAt(i);
        st=st+ch;
        if(st.equalsIgnoreCase("The"))
        {
            sen=sen+" "+st;
            st="";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The new string is: "+st);
}
```

**output:**

> The new string is:  big cat is the best

Comment: Your answer is probably more suitable for the OP because it doesn't use built-in methods. I approve.

Comment: no sir this isn't working when i am running it i get blank output next to "the new string is: "

Comment: what's your input?

Comment: `if (ch!=' ')      
{      
    st=st+ch;       

}`

Comment: that's not input, this is some code, you did realize that I did not remove the whole `if` statement, the body of the `if` statement (`st=st+ch;`) is below the  `ch=s.charAt(i);` line

Comment: by that code i was trying to get the word from the string

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all occurrences of a string using [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
String sentence = "This is a sentence.";
String removed = sentence.replaceAll("(?i)this", "");
System.out.println(removed);
```

The `(?i)` will ignore the case of the word.

Output: `" is a sentence."`

Comment: actually my teacher hasn't taught this method yet and so if i use it then i won't get marks, is there any way to do it without using this method?

Comment: @mayank Yes, elefasGR has posted a solution.